# Create a Custom AJAX Control Toolkit Control Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to Create a Custom AJAX Control Toolkit Control Extender by following a tutorial.The link of the tutorial is- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/creating-a-custom-ajax-control-toolkit-control-extender-cs

I followed the steps exactly but i am getting the following error-
[image]

Please help me to solve this error so that I can develop my own toolkit

Comment: try this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31351/Create-Composite-Control-using-Ajax-Toolkit-Contro

Answer (score 0):

As link suggests you need to create a java script file CustomerExtenders.DisableButtonBehaviour.js file and put that as Embedded resource.

There is whole javascript code in that link. Starting with

```
Type.registerNamespace('CustomExtenders');
```

Make sure you have given correct name given at both places in .js file as well as following code.

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("CustomExtenders.DisabledButtonBehavior.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Comment: ya i checked I have given correct names but still it give the same error